# Firebase emulator from local network

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cli, firebase-tools

firebase command `firebase emulators:start` all ports and hosts work fine on my pc but but if I try from different device in my network (ohter pc) to access network-ip:8080 I get connection refused.

This does not worked:

```
firebase.firestore().useEmulator("0.0.0.0", 8080);
```

But this worked:

```
firebase.firestore().useEmulator("192.168.x.x", 8080);
```

Why first one was not working but second one worked did not understand the reason behind this

Answer (score 2):

0.0.0.0 is not a valid destination address for outgoing connections, such as those being made by the Firebase SDK to connect to the emulator.  It is only a valid incoming address for services that want to listen on all possible IP addresses assign to the machine where it's running.

I recommend doing a web search for "ip address 0.0.0.0" to read more.

Comment: if i use hostname as `0.0.0.0` or `localhost` i can test it with my pc but not on other pc on local network. but if i use `192.168.x.x` i can test it on local network but not on my pc. Is there any solution

Comment: If you have a new question, please post it separately and explain in more detail what isn't working the way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the port that you are trying to connect to is opened? I ran through the same issue with Ubuntu firewall blocking the request. If you are using Ubuntu use this command to open the port.

```
    sudo ufw allow 9299
```